# How to count in nested if statement in matlab?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, count

I want to increment the count and display the value in a message box. I'm using a nested if statement. This is my code

```
if sum( abs( f1(:) - f2(:))) == 0.0
       i = i + 1;
elseif sum(abs(f2(:) - f3(:))) == 0.0
       i = i+ 1;
elseif sum(abs(f3(:) - f4(:))) == 0.0
       i = i + 1;
else 
       i = 1;   
end

h = msgbox('Perfect  = %d',i);
```

Here `f1`,`f2`,`f3`, and `f4` contains the difference between two images in float. I have declared `i = 0;` before if statement. Still I'm not able to see the message box in the output. I tried with `disp()` function too, but its showing only the `else` part i.e, `i = 1`

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could be a floating point precision issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab

Comment: @Divakar I'm using `i` only for counting. Float will not affect that I guess.

Comment: .@Divakar is refering to the exact equalities of the sums to `0`.  If the `f*` vectors are doubles, exactly equating to `0` is fairly difficult to achieve in floating point in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each mutually exclusive branch of your decision tree is either `i=i+1` or `i=1`. *No matter which one runs*, if `i` was zero before, it will be one afterwards.

I did not understand what you want, but the code as written checks for several conditions and does the same thing no matter what, which can't be right.

Edit: try this

```
if sum( abs( f1(:) - f2(:))) == 0.0
   i = i + 1;
end
if sum(abs(f2(:) - f3(:))) == 0.0
   i = i+ 1;
end
if sum(abs(f3(:) - f4(:))) == 0.0
   i = i + 1;
end

h = msgbox('Perfect  = %d',i);
```

This will give you a count of the number of matches, from zero to three. Now all conditions are checked independently, before the second one would only be checked if the first one was false.

Comment: Actually I need to display how much if the input is perfect and how much it not matching. So for that I'm using count. Is there any other way to know the perfect and not perfect count. Do I have to change the if statement or something?